# Javascript - Checking Field if it contains a number works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a text input referencing a person's name.

I have 3 validations, depending on whether the input is too short, null or it is a number. The Validations works if there has been no input, or the input is too short, but the number validation does not work.

If the input is 123 -> Validation says CORRECTLY that only numbers are allowed.
If the input is s123 or 123s or 1s23 -> Validation says nothing about numbers.

```
function formValidation(){
    var emp_lname = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
    if(emp_lname.length <=2){
        document.getElementById('last_name').style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById('last_name_errors').innerHTML="Last Name is way too short!!!";
        if(emp_lname === ""){
            document.getElementById('last_name').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById('last_name_errors').innerHTML="Please enter a Last Name!!!";
        }
        returned_value = false;
    }
    if (/^\d+$/.test(document.getElementById('last_name').value)) {
        document.getElementById('last_name').style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById('last_name_errors').innerHTML="Last Name must NOT contain numbers!!!";
        returned_value = false;
    }
return returned_value;
}
```

This is the exact output:

**Correct:**

[image]

**Correct:**

[image]

**False:**

[image]

**EDIT:** JSFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/vagg77/jv0ofnxr/

Comment: can you please share the html

Comment: added a JSFiddle link, but no idea why JS fails there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the last IF to:

```
if (document.getElementById('last_name').value.match( /(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)/ ) ) {

    document.getElementById('last_name').style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById('last_name_errors').innerHTML="Last Name must NOT contain numbers!!!";
    returned_value = false;
}
```

Comment: happy to help :)